# web3.py createFilter : TypeError: Unsupported type: '<class 'list'>'. Must be one of: bool, str, bytes, bytearrayor int

Tags: python, blockchain, smartcontracts

I write the contract,

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract voteEXample{

    event getVoterAndVoted(address voter,bytes32 voted);
    mapping(bytes32 => uint8) public receivedVotes;

    function vote(bytes32 toVote) public{
        require(check(toVote));
        receivedVotes[toVote] += 1;
        emit getVoterAndVoted(msg.sender,toVote);
    }

}
```

And through web3.py, I deployed the contract successfully. But, I failed in using the createFilter method.

```
greeter = w3.eth.contract(address=address,abi = abi)
transfer_filter = greeter.events.getVoterAndVoted.createFilter(fromBlock="0x0")
```

The createFilter occurs the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/SEAC/experiment/VoteTest.py", line 103, in <module>
    transfer_filter = greeter.events.getVoterAndVoted.createFilter(fromBlock="0x0") 
  File "C:\Users\jinpp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 20, in _wrapper
    return self.method(objtype, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jinpp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\web3\contract.py", line 1231, in createFilter
    log_filter = filter_builder.deploy(self.web3)
  File "C:\Users\jinpp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\web3\_utils\events.py", line 408, in deploy
    log_filter = cast("LogFilter", w3.eth.filter(self.filter_params))
  File "C:\Users\jinpp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\web3\_utils\events.py", line 393, in filter_params
    "topics": self.topics,
  File "C:\Users\jinpp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\web3\_utils\events.py", line 381, in topics
    return normalize_topic_list(cons(to_hex(self.event_topic), arg_topics))
  File "C:\Users\jinpp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\eth_utils\decorators.py", line 76, in wrapper
    return to_wrap(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jinpp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\eth_utils\conversions.py", line 50, in to_hex
    "or int.".format(repr(type(primitive)))
TypeError: Unsupported type: '<class 'list'>'.  Must be one of: bool, str, bytes, bytearrayor int.
```

I don't  know why this problem happens. Can anyone tell me. Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem, except with a contract function call. I think that it's happening when the addresses are converted to hex, as the last thing I see before the type error is:

```
File "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/eth_utils/conversions.py", line 48, in to_hex
    raise TypeError(...
```

I have a hunch it's because we're not converting the addresses to checksum, as I know needs to be done in web3.py. I'm gonna try that first in my work and post back. I'm using Python 3.9 on Ubuntu 20.04 (I think, just wiped my old MacBook and threw it on there so all this would work).